# How to integrate NativeScript into @nrwl/nx

Tags: angular, nrwl

How to share code between multiple [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) apps and multiple Angular apps using [@nrwl/nx](https://nrwl.io/nx) (Nx Workspace)?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://nstudio.io/xplat/. It seems these guys are trying to make it easier, but it still isn't an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out [xplat](https://nstudios.io/xplat/). It did look promising but I was trying to integrate into an existing codebase and it felt disjointed trying to figure out what belonged in their core and how I was supposed to deal with all the existing modules each with their own service that used HttpClientModule and needed to be converted to using the NativeScript version.

Instead, I ended up going with the Code Sharing approach that NativeScript recommends. [Code Sharing](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro)

This method complicates the folder structure as you duplicate any file in-place that needs to be different for NativeScript. Basically, you add `.tns` just before the file extension. Then it uses some build tools that use those files when they are there.